# Run vim function inside ex command

Tags: shell, vim, command, neovim

I want to switch the current working directory of the tab to the current global working directory. How do I do that as a mapping?

I tried to make a mapping as follows

`nnoremap <leader>tcd :tcd getcwd()<CR>:pwd<CR>`

But it looks like `:tcd` expects a path. How do I evaluate getcwd() inside so it returns the path as a string?

Tried `echo` and `call` but it seems like I am doing it wrong ...

Comment: May I ask you what's the meaning of `tcd`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have tcd installed, so untested:

```
nnoremap <leader>tcd :execute "tcd " . getcwd()<CR>:pwd<CR>
```

Comment: May I ask you what's the meaning of `tcd`?

Comment: @Rainning It’s a command from a plug-in https://github.com/vim-scripts/tcd.vim

Answer (score 0):

:exec to execute a string as a vim exec command so :exec 'tcd '.

:call system() to get the output of a shell command, but i don't see how getcwd is going to get anything different than the vim :pwd command or the shell ls command.